# How to replace string with another string by index?

Tags: java, replace

I have a string like this- 11/15/2013. 
I want to replace 2013 with 2000 (last 2 digits with 0). how to do this?

Comment: `String.replace(...)` ?

Comment: google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234510/how-do-i-replace-a-character-in-a-string-in-java

Comment: but what are the parameters within (...)? Is there any direct way to replace string by index?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it seems you should learn a little about the language you are programming in. I hope these are homework problems and you aren't getting paid for this... I suggest you bookmark this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ and make it your FIRST stop when you run into a problem.  We are glad to help with legitmate problems, but not trivial stuff.  And your rep will take fewer hits...

Comment: It's worth noting that strings are immutable (cannot be changed) as such you will actually get a new string with those characters changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always do replace `date.replace("13", "00");`

but if you are looking at something generic of a solution (In case if you are not aware of what the last 2 digits are, yet you want them to be '00') you can do something like this :

```
String date = "11/15/2013";
String newDate = date.substring(0,8)+"00";
```

Or you can use a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder date = new StringBuilder("11/15/2013");
date.setCharAt(8, '0');
date.setCharAt(9, '0');
```

or

```
StringBuilder date = new StringBuilder("11/15/2013");
date.replace(8, 10, "00");
```

Comment: yeah this is the answer..:)

Comment: @G.Madri if it is useful please accept it, so that it will be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 1):

code snippet

```
String date = "11/15/2013";
String replaced = date.replace("2013","2000");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to replace a sequence at a certain index of a `String`, use a `StringBuilder`:

```
String replaced = new StringBuilder(date)
    .replace(8, 10, "00").toString();
```

Comment: I'm getting the system time and replace it's year by 2000. So I don't know the year of the system time.This is what I really wanted :)

Comment: Fine. Sidenote: Make sure that the position of the year never changes - i.e. day and month should always be two digits (e.g. "07/03" for 7th of march).

Answer (score 1):

```
 String date = "11/15/2013";
 System.out.println(date.substring(0, date.length()-2).concat("00"));
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Better code snippet

```
String replaced = date.replace("11/15/2013.","11/15/2000");
```