# Number of Times a Character in String using java?

Tags: java

I searched for method to calculate how many times a character is in String and found a good solution

```
temp.length() - temp.replaceAll("T", "").length()
```

here,we are calculating the number of time 'T' is in temp...

Problem is,it is not working properly for '.'

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String temp="TTT..####";
    System.out.println(temp.length() - temp.replaceAll("T", "").length());
    System.out.println(temp.length() - temp.replaceAll(".", "").length());
    System.out.println(temp.length() - temp.replaceAll("#", "").length());
}
```

OutPut:

```
run:
3
9
4
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

according to output '.' is 9 times in String.through loop it's gives the right answer.
What is the problem??

Comment: "found a good solution" well, perhaps not *good*, but certainly *short*.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1234762/545127

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I replace a character in a string in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234510/how-do-i-replace-a-character-in-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `replaceAll("\\.", "").length());`

`replaceAll()` takes a `REGEX` as input. `.` has a special meaning in REGEX, it means *any character*. You need to escape it by using 2 `\\`s

EDIT:

Use :

```
String temp = "TTT..####";
System.out.println(temp.split("\\.", -1).length - 1);
```

// using `-1` as *limit* in `split()` divides the String based on the passed argument (and gives empty Strings as result, if needed). So, in the split array you will have `n+1` elements, where `n` is the number of occurances of the particular argument. So, we are doing `length-1`.

Comment: before i was using temp.split("#").length-1'#' and '.' were generating error.solved for '.' using your change.but not working for '#'Any suggestion?

Comment: @SameerAzeem - You don't need to escape the `#`. `System.out.println(temp.length() - temp.replaceAll("#", "").length());` will work.. Is it not working?

Comment: it's working but temp.split("#").length-1 is more short and also for info.plz?

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll()` takes a regex and `.` mathces any `char`. This is the reason why your output is 9 in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can find the number of times for every character in one iteration like this

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++)
{
    char c = temp.charAt(i);
    if(!map.containsKey(c))
    {
        map.put(c, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        map.put(c, map.get(c)+1);
    }
}
for(Character c : map.keySet())
{
    System.out.println("" + c + " : " + map.get(c));
}
```

People have already answered that you need to use `\\.` instead of `.` in the regex. I just figured this could be a slightly more general solution for this particular problem with some minor alteration.