# Replacing two different character using regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I have this string

`"<code>...code1....</code><code><b>kjkjk</b></code>".replaceAll("\\<.*?>","&gt;");`

**expected output**
`<code>...code1....</code><code>&gt;b&lt;kjkjk &lt;/b&lt;</code>`

what i want to do is replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;` between all `<code>` tag using single regular expression.
How can i do that ? Is it possible using single regular expression or i will have do separate `replaceAll()` for `<` and `>` ?

Comment: is it a homework or why do you impose a limitation on the number of `replace` calls?

Comment: I think multiple `replaceAll` will process the same string again and again

Comment: Do you _need_ to use a regular expression?  If not, there are more efficient ways: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234510/how-do-i-replace-a-character-in-a-string-in-java/1234531#1234531

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure you encode only the characters between that  why don't you first extract it out of  and then do myString.replaceAll("\<([^\<\>]*)\>","<" + "$1" + ">"); Otherwise you are going to end up with a very ugly regex that will not be easy to read.