# How do I replace comma with dot in EditText in case of Portuguese

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext, textwatcher

The validation in EditText (numberDecimal) is working fine with English language. I mean, the decimal separator as expected.

I am trying to replace dot with comma in case of Portuguese.

I have tried some solutions but those solutions allow multiple commas where I am expecting the behaviour as dot.

Here is what I have tried but it's allowing multiple commas inside after text changed:

```
if(device lang is portoguese){

edittext.keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789,")

}
```

Comment: can you have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234510/how-do-i-replace-a-character-in-a-string-in-java

Comment: yes but comma should be only once not multiple time

Comment: U can replace all commas with empty string except first place/last .. Or Store index of loc then insert it Again

Answer (score 0):

Try with Locale.
 Get the locale instance of the user and based on locale like below:

```
  public static String formatNumber(double number, Locale locale) {
        NumberFormat formatter = DecimalFormat.getInstance(locale);
        formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(MAXIMUM_FRACTION_DIGITS);
        formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(MINIMUM_FRACTION_DIGITS);
        if (locale == null || formatter == null) {
            return "";
        }

        return format(number);
    }
```

Now, call formateNumber() method and set in your edit-text.