# Get a string that matches the original string except that all of the ‘m’s have been replaced with ‘M’s: (JAVA)

Tags: java

So if I were to have the string

```
String str = " mommy ";
```

How would I get the output

```
"MoMMy"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace a character in a string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234510/how-do-i-replace-a-character-in-a-string-in-java)

Comment: str.replaceAll("m", "M");

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired output , you can follow the following code

```
    String str = "mommy";

    char [] str1 = str.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        if(str1[i] == 'm'){
            str1[i] = 'M';
        }
    }

    String str2 = new String(str1);
    System.out.println(str2);
```